# MySQL - Pull random row and ensure no conflict

Tags: mysql, sql

This is kind of an odd question and  I really didn't know how to word the title.

I have an engine that is pulling 2 items for comparison at random.

When you "vote" for one of them, it will log to a table the ID the item selected and the item not selected.

I want to prevent that combination from being pulled ever again, and I'd like to do it in a single query or two if possible.

Ultimately ALL items will have been compared, and as such it will only return a single row.

Example table structure:

```
id, user_id, selected_item_id, not_selected_item_id
```

I need to ensure when I do a query on the `item` table that it does not pull records that conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will choose two random items that you have not voted on yet:

```
SELECT i.item_id
FROM items i
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v 
  ON i.item_id IN (v.selected_item_id, v.not_selected_item_id)
WHERE v.id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

This is not very efficient either for the join or for the random selection. But it's adequate for small data sets.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column ***picked*** to the ***item*** table to indicate whether an item has been picked or not, and then select two records randomly with the condition ***picked***=0.